# how to access the parent object property? in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Tried few ways but didnt work for me.. what i need If i click on BUTTON ... i want to access the VALUE of li of same in jquery...

```
<div id="categoryListings">            
<ul class="list-group">
    <li value="501" class="list-group-item">
    Bikes <a type="button">Delete </a>
    </li>

    <li value="502 " class="list-group-item">
    Bikes <a type="button">Delete </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: What "value" You need?

Comment: tried to user extra DIV and span but above code i made it simple... i know the THIS attribute but its not LI .. user will click on Button.. confusing for me

Comment: value of li.. .thats 501 .. 502.. so on with li

Answer (score 1):

`value` isn't a valid attribute on `li` elements. If you want to use a custom attribute you can use `data-value` instead:

```
<li data-value="501" ... >
```

After changing that, `type` isn't a valid attribute on `a` elements. As with before, here you can use `data-type` instead:

```
<a data-type="button">
```

With jQuery you can then:

```
$('.list-group').on('click', 'a[data-type="button"]', function() {
    var liValue = $(this).parent().attr('data-value');
});
```

Comment: you can also mention to use the `.data()` function in order to get the values

Comment: @VDesign `data()` is great, but I'd prefer to use `attr()` in this case. `data()` only reads the values held within the `data-*` attribute the first time the DOM is traversed. If this value is then modified, `data()` will not reflect the change. With `attr()`, you will always be given the most up-to-date value.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/x34cvrt3/2/)

jquery

```
a = [];
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $("li").each(function () {
        var valueThis = $(this).attr('value');
        a.push(valueThis);
        $(".valuesHere").text(a);
    });
});
```